# Jquery click event to on load event

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to trigger on click button .How can I change this when page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideleft button').click(function() {
    var $lefty = $(this).next();
    $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() :      0});
  });
}
```

My html

```
<div id="slideleft" class="slide">
<button>slide it</button>
<div class="inner" style="left: -350px;">Animate this element's left style property</div>
</div>
```

I want to slide in when the page load not clicking the button.

Comment: Put the `animate` call directly in the `.ready()` function, not in the `click` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the code when document is ready or on widow load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#slideleft button').next();
    $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() :      0});
}
```

on window load

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $lefty = $('#slideleft button').next();
    $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() :      0});
});
```

for speed

```
$lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() : 0}, 1000);
```

the 1000 is 1000 milliseconds, you can also add callback on animation complete, for more details go to http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Thank you .Is there any way to control slide speed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely loading the page then the effect start you can do this :

```
$(window).load(function () {

     var $lefty = $('#slideleft button').next();
     $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() :      0});

});
```

This effect starts after finishing page loading.
But if you want to start the effect real time you can use this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var $lefty = $('#slideleft button').next();
     $lefty.animate({left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ? -$lefty.outerWidth() :      0});

});
```